# Azure Devops azure-pipelines.yml for each branch

Tags: angular, azure, deployment, azure-devops

I have an angular project with dev and master branches and want the following: An test environment and production in Azure Devops. When something gets commited to dev I want the dev branch code to be deployed to the test environent, when code gets commited to master, I want the master branch to be deployed to the production environment.

My question is as follows: I need 2 artifacts based on "ng build --dev" and "ng build --prod". How can I achieve this? Do I need to add a "azure-pipelines.yml" file to the master and dev branch? If so, if I merge dev to master, the "azure-pipelines.yml" from dev gets merged with master... What is the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use `ng build --prod` in **all** of your stages. You should have only **one** build stage for you app that builds the applications and publish the artifacts (binaries) to use them within your deployment stages (e. g. dev / prod).

Using this approach, you can test the **same** binaries in a test environment before you publish them to prod. In prod, you might use other configurations for your application, but the binaries itself should be the same.

Also, I would introduce an approvement-process before you deploy to your production environment instead of automatically deploy to it.

In short: Create a Multi-Stage-Pipeline that automatically builds the app and deploys it to your test environment after a push to dev / master. For the prod deployment, add approval checks and a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions) to ensure that only builds from the master branch can deploy to that stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Two questions: 
- Why should I make use of a multi-staged-pipeline? 
- How can I have the correct configuration if I always do the build by using "ng build --prod"?

Comment: The multi-stage-pipelines are the new way to implement CI / CD. There are multiple ways to retrieve configurations in Angular. If you host you application e. g. using ASP.NET Core, you can create a Settings controller that returns the configuration dynamically.

Comment: hi, thanks again! The multi-stage-pipeline is just using the yaml file instead of the UI? Of is it an advanced usage of the yaml file? Hop to hear from you!

Comment: Using the YAML file, you will have your Pipelines inside your repository and the pipelines will always match to the state of your application. For example, if your application uses a SQL Database in Version 1 and you switch to e. g. CosmosDB in version 2, depending on which version (commit) you deploy, the pipeline will match to your application.

Comment: My very last question!: You said "I would recommend to use ng build --prod in all of your stages.". Do I need to define in the trigger section all branches for the yaml file to run for? If so, does this yaml file have to be in all the branches defined in the trigger section?

Comment: You can use leave the branch property if you want the pipeline to get triggered for all branches. Or you can use the include or exclude schema to specify it. You can also use wildcards here, for example ```- releases/*```. See: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-triggers.md